# PostgreSQL grouping error group by table that is only there sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4.2

This is a strange issue. I am using PG search as well as some home made classes to populate search results on my site. The home made classes are tags to further refine the search. For example you search for food and you want organic so you reduce the search results by those not tagged as organic and food. It worked fine for quite a while.

This all started after I upgraded to 4.2.1 rails.

I've been able to trace the error to a specific line of code:

```
 joins(:tags).where(tags: {id: tag_list }).group("businesses.id").having("count(*) 
 = #{tag_list.size}")
```

This line of code is a part of the following function:

```
  def self.tagged_with_all(tag_list)
   unless tag_list.empty?
     joins(:tags).where(tags: {id: tag_list }).group("businesses.id").having("count(*) = #{tag_list.size}")
  else
   all
  end
 end
```

The error looks like this:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "pg_search_businesses.rank" must 
appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...UP BY businesses.id HAVING count(*) = 1  ORDER BY pg_search_...
```

So I thought why not just follow the error's advice and add pg_search_business.rank to the aggregate so the troublesome line from above becomes:

```
 joins(:tags).where(tags: {id: tag_list }).group("businesses.id", 
 "pg_search_business.rank").having("count(*) 
 = #{tag_list.size}")
```

This works part of the time but pg_search_business.rank is not always present at when this function is called. And for these times if I use the code directly above I get the following error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table 
"pg_search_businesses"LINE 1: ...."name" = 'Kid Friendly') 
GROUP BY businesses.id, pg_search_
```

I now am wondering if there is a reliable way to check for pg_search_business.rank's presence within the scope of the function or if there is a better for more RoR way to deal with this particular issue.

The error is occurring when the method self.tagged_with_all is getting called outside of the scope of the pg_search.

What I'm running up against are two separate grouping issues one in which we must group using pg_search_businesses.rank and another in which we must not. I am seeking the best way to resolve this.

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm new to coding in ruby and this is my first ruby related question so let me know if I can provide you with more info.

Comment: So sometimes you're using the `tagged_with_all` scope when using PG Search and sometimes you're using it for other purposes?

Comment: That would be correct. Let me modify my question.

Comment: Not an answer because I don't know anything about pg_search but you can call `.group` multiple times and it will do The Right Thing (i.e. `x.group(:a).group(:b)` is `GROUP BY a, b`).

Comment: I was basically already doing this and it works great when pg_search is getting used but when I am calling this method without pg_search I get this error  PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "pg_search_businesses"
LINE 1: ...."name" = 'Kid Friendly') GROUP BY businesses.id, pg_search_

Comment: But you need to call `group` once inside the scope and again outside the scope, no?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Could you elaborate?

Comment: When you're using pg_search, you'd say `x.tagged_with_all(...).group("pg_search_business.rank")`, otherwise you'd just `x.tagged_with_all(...)` and there'd be no mention of `pg_search_business.rank` inside the scope.

Comment: That is correct. That actually got me on the path to the correct answer. I appreciate your help with this issue.

Comment: You might want to answer your own question to help future searchers.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @mu is too short

The issue was tracked down to adding a variable that gets set outside the scope of the function in question. This is, at present, the only way to track when **pg_search_businesses.rank** will be needed in the grouping.

I added the following logic to set a global variable $group_text

```
    unless q.empty?
     $group_text = "businesses.id" + "," + " pg_search_businesses.rank"
    else
     $group_text = "businesses.id"
    end
```

Here is the function that I added the code to (so that you can tell what q is and where it is coming from.

```
  def self.search(q)
    unless q.empty?
     $group_text = "businesses.id" + "," + " pg_search_businesses.rank"
    else
     $group_text = "businesses.id"
    end
    unless q.empty?
      search_text(q)
    else
      all
    end
  end
```

This seems to work as a solution but I am still open to alternate methods for solving this particular issue as this one feels a bit hacked.

thanks again to SO and mu is too short